# How to link 2 sub procedures in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to use **VBA** code to:

1. First highlight all the non-empty cell in a column
2. Then replace those non-empty cells with two lines of content in one cell.

But when I run my code, only the function `UseLineFeedCharacter` is working, and it replaces all cells with the new content.

I don't know if it is because I didn't link those two sub procedures together or not. Thank you for helping out!!!
My code is like this:

```
Sub UseLinefeedCharacter()
    Dim str  As String
    str = "Line 1" & vbLf & "Line 2" & vbLf & "Line 3"
    With [a1]
        .Value = str
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Sub qwerty()
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rSel As Range

Set rng = Range("B2:C7")
Set rSel = Nothing

For Each r In rng
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        If rSel Is Nothing Then
            Set rSel = r
        Else
            Set rSel = Union(rSel, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
If Not rSel Is Nothing Then rSel.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this task.

You can create another routine that calls both procedures:

```
Sub Main
    UseLinefeedCharacter
    qwerty
End Sub
```

Which you will just run `Main`, or you can just call the other Sub from the first one.

```
Sub UseLinefeedCharacter()
    Dim str  As String
    str = "Line 1" & vbLf & "Line 2" & vbLf & "Line 3"
    With [a1]
        .Value = str
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With
    qwerty      '<-- Called qwerty sub
End Sub
```

This obviously depends on the scope of each sub. If one is located in a different module and is a `Private Sub`, then this will not work.